# xlabel and ylabel for facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm doing like this:

```
ggplot(IDPlotLn, aes(x=CO3, y=CRf)) + 
  xlab(xlabel) + 
  ylab(ylabel)  +
  opts(
      axis.text.x = theme_text(size=10, face="plain", colour="black",vjust=1), 
      axis.text.y = theme_text(size=10, face="plain", colour="black", hjust=1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.3 , 1.3), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  opts(panel.margin=unit(1, "cm")) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F) + 
  facet_wrap(~ ID, nrow=7, ncol=3, scales = "free") +
  opts(strip.text.x = theme_text(size = 8))
```

I want to plot Xlabel and ylabel for each one of my facet, the same xlabel and ylabel.  Like this I have only one xlabel and ylabel for all of the facet.

Is it possible?

---

Thank you for yours answer, I didn't know gridExtra.

But in this example, I'm faceting and I just want to make it more beautiful, it is the same xlabel and ylabel that I want to add for each panel.
Because after for I want to choose several panels from all my panels, so it can be nice if I have already x and y label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use different labels for the x and y axes when *faceting* then the correct answer is that you probably shouldn't be using facets. The entire point of faceting is that each panel *shares* the same x and y axis. So if you're labeling them differently, chances are you're misusing faceting.

What you probably want instead is to simply plot each panel separately and then arrange them in a grid. This can be easily done in `ggplot2` with the help of the `gridExtra` package:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5,3),
        y = rnorm(15),
        z = rep(letters[1:3],each = 5))

dat <- split(dat,dat$z)

p1 <- ggplot(dat[[1]],aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        labs(x = 'xlabel1',y='ylabel1')

p2 <- ggplot(dat[[2]],aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        labs(x = 'xlabel2',y='ylabel2')

p3 <- ggplot(dat[[3]],aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        labs(x = 'xlabel3',y='ylabel3')

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3)]
```

[image]

See `?grid.arrange` for more examples.

Comment: joran- Your point "The entire point of faceting is that each panel shares the same x and y axis." Should it not be just x axis. Y axis can be compleley independent as long as they share the same x axis. Correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: @2sb My point was that faceting is intended for circumstances when _at least_ one axis is shared. The OP wanted to label _both_ axes differently in each panel, which sort of defeats the purpose of faceting.

Comment: joran- "When at least one axis is shared", this is better. Thanks.